# Evaluate $\int \vert z\vert dz $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have to compute the integral $\int \vert z\vert dz $ following the next paths:

1)through the radio vector of the point $z=2-i$

2)through the semicircumference $\vert z\vert=1$, $0\le argz\le \pi$ (the path begins at the point $z=1$)

3)through the semicircumference $\vert z\vert=1$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le argz\le \frac{\pi}{2}$ (the path begins at the point $z=-i$)

4)through circumference $\vert z\vert=R$

The **solution** for 4) I think is $\int_R \vert z\vert dz=0 $ because  $\vert z\vert=R$ it's a closed Jordan curve.

for 3), I have this $\int_J{|z|}\mathrm{dz}=-\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}ie^{i\theta}d\theta=-i\frac{e^{i\theta}}{i}|_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}=-e^{\frac{i3\pi}{2}}+e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}=-(-i)+i=2i$

For 2), I have this $\int_J{|z|}\mathrm{dz}=\int_{0}^{\pi}ie^{i\theta}d\theta=e^{i\pi}-1=-2$

And for 1) I don't know how to integrate. The curve is a line?

Can someone help me with 1)? Also are my others answers  correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Be careful: $|z|$ is NOT analytic, so, integrals over closed path are not necessarily $0$.

Comment: @Basti: Very true, but on $|z|=R$, $|z|$ is constant, and we have just the integral $R\int_C dz$ for a closed curve $C$.

Comment: On 3) why are the limits of integration $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{3\pi}{2}$?

Comment: I just interchange the way of the path, therefore I have to use the '-' sign. @sharding4

Comment: @NombreFalso123 if $|z|$ were analytic, or any other function, then the integral over any closed path will be always $0$, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your English, but if you are asking in (1) to integrate along the line segment from the origin to the point $2-i$, you should parametrize that path by $z(t) = t(2-i)$, $0\le t\le 1$. Now what is
$$\int_C |z|dz = \int_0^1 |z(t)|z'(t)\,dt = \int_0^1 \sqrt 5t(2-i)\,dt?$$

Comment: yes that's what I meant.

Comment: Are my other calculations correct?

Comment: No, on (3), you should have gone from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$. You went around the left semicircle instead of the right semicircle.

Comment: how did you parametrize the path from $0$ to $2-i$? or why $0\le t\le 1$?

Comment: This is the standard way to parametrize a line segment, as you learned in multivariable calculus.

Comment: hmm for your information, I don't remember it